# Wiremock response depending on request body parameter

Tags: json, response, wiremock

I am sending Wiremock (Standalone, 2.21) a request with the body

```
{
        "attribute1": "value1",
        "attribute2": "value2",
        ...
        "attributen": "valuen"
}
```

to the URL `/test/test-url` , no query parameters, with `POST`.
I would like it to do the following:

- respond with "response1.json" when attribute1 equals "text1"
- respond with "response2.json" when attribute1 equals "text2"
- respond with "response_general.json" when attribute1 equals something else than "text1" or "text2"

The other attributes dont matter regarding the answer.
I would like to do this by only using .json files. Thank you!

Comment: Is this still an issue for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was to have check for body patterns and have 3 mappings for the 3 different cases:

One for the case when text1 is detected:

```
       "request": {
          "method": "POST",
          "urlPattern":"/.*",
          "bodyPatterns": [
            {
              "contains":"\"attribute1\": \"text1\""
            }
          ]
        },
        "response": {
          "status": 200,
          "bodyFileName": "response_text1.json",
          "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        }
```

One for the case when text2 is detected:

```
      "request": {
          "method": "POST",
          "urlPattern":"/.*",
          "bodyPatterns": [
            {
              "contains":"\"attribute1\": \"text2\""
            }
          ]
        },
        "response": {
          "status": 200,
          "bodyFileName": "response_text2.json",
          "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        }
```

One for the case when neither is detected. In this case a general    answer is given back.

```
        "request": {
            "method": "POST",
            "urlPattern": "/.*"
        },
        "response": {
              "status": 200,
              "bodyFileName": "response_general.json",
              "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
              }
            }
```

Comment: Although this may resolve your issue today. If you have to use this approach a lot, then maintenance will become a challenge. Which rules belong together. For this reason I'd still recommend you have a closer look at the [HandleBars helpers](http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/#handlebars-helpers) that would allow for logic to create a single response rule.

Answer (score 1):

In the more recent versions of WireMock (2.19+) there is support for [HandleBars processing in the BodyFileName](http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/#templated-body-file) attribute. This then allows you to do put a (partial) name in the JSON request body and then reuse it's value for the filename reference.

```
{
  "request" : {
    "urlPathPattern" : "/jpathFile",
    "method" : "GET",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": {
            "equalTo": "application/json"
        }
    }

  },
  "response" : {
    "status" : 200,
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "bodyFileName" : "/{{jsonPath request.body '$.attribute2'}}",
    "transformers": ["response-template"]
  }
}
```

Input message:

```
{
    "attribute1": "value1",
    "attribute2": "response.json",
    "attributen": "valuen"
}
```

the `response.json` in the `/__files/response.json` location:

```
{
    "hello": "World!"
}
```

Comment: This doesnt take care of the case when the value "unexpected_value" is sent with "attribute2" and i dont have a unexpected_value.json ready in the __files folder.

Comment: Do you mean the actual string "unexpected_value" or _a random unexpected  value_? The latter requires insight in the files in the file system, the former you can use the HandleBars comparison operators for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "contains" or "equalTo" i would suggest to use "matchesJsonPath"

```
"bodyPatterns": [
        {
            "matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.attribute1 == 'value1')]"
        }
]
```